# Динамическое размещение элементов в svg

Tags: javascript, svg

Как в SVG  на равных расстояниях друг от друга (статично) разместить несколько генерируемых окружностей по периметру прямоугольника(с заданными размерами и координатами), как привязаться к его координатам?

Comment: или двигать ваши генерируемые окружности по path

Comment: Интересует возможность статичного размещения элементов (окружностей) по периметру прямоугольника, они будут элементами графа.Я знаю формулу для размещения элементов по окружности, с расчётом размещения по периметру прямоугольника не получается..

Comment: используем path как путь для ваших генерируемых окружностей , примерно так https://codepen.io/Sverstka/pen/NqGdQP?editors=1010

Comment: Спасибо, хотелось бы без Snap - пишу во vue js, (из-за некоторых условий) не могу использовать библиотеки в этом компоненте графа..Ищу простенький пример с математическим расчётом  координат ..

Comment: при чём сразу snap можно и на smil сделать - я показал пример от snap.svg.js ...можно просто smil

Comment: Так вам статически нужно или динамически? В заголовке темы одно, в описании - другое.

Comment: Статически нужно...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В svg есть команда `pattern`, которая позволяет равномерно разместить фигуру или комбинацию фигур внутри любого объекта.  Наполнение патерном идёт, как укладка плитки,- первый ряд слева-направо, далее заполнение второго ряда и т.д. Паттерн очень мощный инструмент со множеством аттрибутов. Более подробно о патернах можно почитать [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Patterns) и [здесь](https://svg-art.ru/?page_id=875).

*Идея - использовать паттерн для  равномерного размещения окружностей по периметру прямоугольника:*

- Заполняем паттерном большой прямоугольник:

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 200 200"  >  
  
<defs>
<pattern id="patternCircle"
             x="0" y="0" width="16" height="16"
             patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" >
               
            <circle id="crc1" r="4" cx="5" cy="5" fill="skyblue" stroke="green"/> 
      </pattern>

</defs> 
 <rect width="122" height="122" stroke="black"  style=" fill: url(#patternCircle);" />

</svg>
```

- Сверху размещаем второй прямоугольник, чтобы спрятать лишние
  окружности:

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 200 200"  >  
  
<defs>
<pattern id="patternCircle"
             x="0" y="0" width="16" height="16"
             patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" >
               
            <circle id="crc1" r="4" cx="5" cy="5" fill="skyblue" stroke="green"/> 
      </pattern>

</defs> 
 <rect width="122" height="122" stroke="black"  style="fill: url(#patternCircle);" />
 <rect x="10" y="10" width="102" height="102" stroke="black" fill="#d5d5d5"  />
</svg>
```

- и убираем лишние рамки:

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 200 200"  >  
  
<defs>
<pattern id="patternCircle"
             x="0" y="0" width="16" height="16"
             patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" >
               
            <circle id="crc1" r="4" cx="5" cy="5" fill="skyblue" stroke="green"/> 
      </pattern>

</defs> 
 <rect width="122" height="122" stroke="none"  style="fill: url(#patternCircle);" />
 <rect x="10" y="10" width="102" height="102" stroke="none" fill="#d5d5d5"  />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

Это SMIL я не знаю почему кружки двигаются не по назначенной траектории но сам смысл я показал..

возможно здесь не будет работать или даже кроме как в Хром не будет работать ..тогда надо скопировать код и всё это хозяйство отрисовать в известных вам библиотеках и запускать уже на js

```html
<svg viewBox="-50 0 400 300" xmlns:xlink="http//www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ev="http//www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  
<rect id="el" x="2.2679" y="49.048" width="204.11" height="208.64" fill="none" stroke="#f69500" stroke-width="2" stroke-opacity="0" />
<g>  
  <path id="path" d="m173.12 154.43a69.402 70.158 0 0 1-69.402 70.158 69.402 70.158 0 0 1-69.402-70.158 69.402 70.158 0 0 1 69.402-70.158 69.402 70.158 0 0 1 69.402 70.158z" fill="none" stroke="#009500" stroke-width="2" />
</g>
  
 <ellipse cx="71.06" cy="115.95" rx="15.119" ry="14.741" fill="blue">
    <animateMotion begin="el.mouseover" dur="10s" repeatCount="indefinite" rotate="auto"  restart="whenNotActive" fill="freeze" >
     <mpath xlink:href="#path" />
    </animateMotion>  
  </ellipse>
 <ellipse cx="106.59" cy="104.61" rx="15.119" ry="14.741" fill="#0f0" >
 <animateMotion begin="el.mouseover + 0.5s" dur="10s" repeatCount="indefinite" rotate="auto"  restart="whenNotActive" fill="freeze" >
     <mpath xlink:href="#path" />
    </animateMotion>    
  </ellipse>
</svg>
```

Comment: работает в сниппете

Comment: Решил с помощью математики и svg-методов(getTotalLength(), getPointAtLength()) , но всё равно спасибо.